# How do I add multiple targets to this code?

Tags: excel, vba

The code below will add contents of A to B and then clear A across the entire column. How do I duplicate this function to have multiple columns with their own targets inside the same sub? Do I have to write a private sub for each?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim T As Range, r As Range

    Set T = Intersect(Target, Range("A:A"))

    If T Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For Each r In T

        With r
            .Offset(0, 1).Value = .Offset(0, 1).Value + .Value
            .ClearContents

        End With

    Next r

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: Yo, Do you want to automatically copy column A->B;C->D;E->F or do you want to copy A->B; C->E; F->D? those require different codes.

Comment: I'm building an inventory sheet and I want every cell in column D to add any number entered in into the same row in column B and then clear the cell in D.  I need this to happen on multiple columns with multiple targets. Always lateral in the same row, but to different columns. The code I entered initially works perfect to add data entered in D over to B. Now I need one that does it from F to C.  I know you can only run one "Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)" per sheet, but I can't seem  to figure out how to create a second procedure/event in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

**Single column:**

Try using `Select Case` with `Target.Column` to determine what to do based on column that had event. Adding a `GetLastRow` function, following helpful comment from @AJD, to ensure only looping populated column range.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Columns.Count <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    Select Case Target.Column
    Case 1
        'col A do something
        ClearRange Target
    Case 2
        'col B do something
        ClearRange Target
        'Etc
    End Select
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Public Sub ClearRange(ByVal T As Range)          '<== This works on the basis Target is a single column
    Dim r As Range, loopRange As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(T.Parent.Name)
    Set loopRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, T.Column), ws.Cells(GetLastRow(ws, T.Column), T.Column))
    If loopRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    'Debug.Print loopRange.Address
    For Each r In loopRange
        With r
            .Offset(0, 1).Value = .Offset(0, 1).Value + .Value
            .ClearContents
        End With
    Next r
End Sub

Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal columnNumber As Long = 1) As Long
    With ws
        GetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function
```

---

**tl;dr;**

**Multi-column:**

You can re-write yours as follows. Though I am not sure what happens with multiple columns. Say, columns A:B, simplest case, were Target, does A get looped transfer and added to B, A gets cleared, B gets looped, added to C and B gets cleared? I wasn't really clear so haven't written anything for the inner part. I simply addressed the title  of how to add more targets. Happy to update upon clarification.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then

    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then

    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Noting that `Target` could span multiple columns?

Comment: Can the target span more than one column?

Comment: so all this code would go into each case?                                                                Dim T As Range, r As Range
Set T = Intersect(Target, Range("A:A"))
If T Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False
For Each r In T
    With r
        .Offset(0, 1).Value = .Offset(0, 1).Value + .Value
        .ClearContents
    End With
Next r
Application.EnableEvents = True                                                                                         I'm still pretty new to this and trying to learn as I go. Found code that worked and trying to tweak it.

Comment: @AJD Oh dear....wasn't thinking. Please feel free to comment on update.

Comment: No. Isn't T basically target so you call a sub passing target as parameter,

Comment: @QHarr: Yes, target could span more than one column. Simple scenario: Select `A1:C5` and `Clear Contents`. Or even select `A1:C5` and fill down using the handle.

Comment: @havokjester: In the multi-column example: `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then`: `ClearRange Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")).EntireColumn`: `End If` (QHarr, I may have not used `EntireColumn` correctly here).

Comment: @havokjester: another way, building on the above is something like: `For Each T In Target.Columns`: `ClearRange T.EntireColumn`: `Next T`

Comment: @havokjester The final consideration is to not iterate over the entire column, but only over the used rows.

Comment: @QHarr: happy for you to take my suggestions into your own answer.

Comment: Why doesn't this work?                                                                                Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim T As Range, r As Range

    Set T = Intersect(Target, Range("D:D"))

    f Not Intersect(Target, Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then
        End If

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For Each r In T

        With r
            .Offset(0, 1).Value = .Offset(0, 1).Value + .Value
            .ClearContents

        End With

    Next r

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
    'continued next comment

Comment: Dim V As Range, r As Range
    Set V = Intersect(Target, Range("F:F"))
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F:F")) Is Nothing Then
        End If
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each r In V
        With r
            .Offset(0, -4).Value = .Offset(0, -4).Value + .Value
            .ClearContents
        End With
    Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Comment: Did you sort this?